# How to implement search function in specific "Activity(Page)" of App Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ide

I have recycler view which contains data of Database(Firebase) in Admin Activity(Page).

There are Name, IC, Phone, Ticket... info of the Users. And my Admin Activity(Page) has recycler view that contains list of Users with their data(info).

I managed to made search function but its searching only for "ONE" String, eg. only Name or only IC..., overall my function searching only for "ONE" variable.

Is it possible to make function in Android Studio (Java) which searching for all the Text appearing on the Screen or on that Activity?

In nutshell, I would like to search for Users as Admin, by their Name, IC, Phone.. with whatever data(info) they have.

```
public class ActivityOfficer extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    MainAdapter mainAdapter;
    DatabaseReference root;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_officer);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    }
        @Override
        protected void onStart () {
            super.onStart();

            root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Visitors");
            if (root != null) {

                root.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if(snapshot.exists()) {
                                FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Model> options =
                                        new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Model>()
                                                .setQuery(root, Model.class)
                                                .build();

                                mainAdapter = new MainAdapter(options);
                                mainAdapter.startListening();
                                recyclerView.setAdapter(mainAdapter);
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStop () {
            super.onStop();
            mainAdapter.startListening();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu){

            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search, menu);
            MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
            SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();

            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                    txtSearch(s);
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                    txtSearch(s);
                    return false;
                }
            });

            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }
```

Search Function, as you can see for now its searching only for "Ticket Numbers" of Users(Visitors).

```
    private void txtSearch(String s) {
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Model> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Model>()
                        .setQuery(root.orderByChild("visitorticket").startAt(s).endAt(s + "~"), Model.class)
                        .build();

        mainAdapter = new MainAdapter(options);
        mainAdapter.startListening();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mainAdapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: you want to perform search on all data exist on firebase (in case of pagination) or search on only visible data(loaded in recycler view)? In case of loaded data please implement filterable in your recyclerview then you can perform search on any item you want have a look at this article  [link] (https://www.howtodoandroid.com/android-recyclerview-search-filter/)

Answer (score 1):

In my project I also used Firebase and searched all the relevant databases.
What I did was take the string that the user entered in the search bar, go through the entire RealTime data base and check if the request is contained there.
If so, return/save it.
Since you are not using a search line (from what I understand from you, you want to search as an admin), you need to create a string that will go through your entire database (in RealTime DB - I simply go through the names of the children (.child) which make up the fields).

I am attaching a code for how I did it and a link to the project.
You are welcome to ask me happily.

My example :

```
  private void performSearch() {
    recyclerViewShow(false);
    final String searchString = mSearchEditText.getText().toString();
    mDbUser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            final List<UserCoach> CoachList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot CoachUser : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                if (CoachUser.child("coachUserName").exists()) {      // if coach user is in firebase
                    System.out.println("Test Test Test");
                        String searchCoachUserName = (String) CoachUser.child("coachUserName").getValue(); // search by name
                        String searchCoachAddress = (String) CoachUser.child("address").getValue(); //search by address
                        if (searchCoachAddress.contains(searchString) || searchCoachUserName.contains(searchString)) {
                            String age = (String) CoachUser.child("age").getValue();
                            String imageUrl = (String) CoachUser.child("profileUrl").getValue();
                            String address = (String) CoachUser.child("address").getValue();
                            String experience = (String) CoachUser.child("experience").getValue();
                            String education = (String) CoachUser.child("education").getValue();
                            String CoachUserName = (String) CoachUser.child("coachUserName").getValue();
                            String gender = (String) CoachUser.child("gender").getValue();
                            CoachList.add(new UserCoach(imageUrl, CoachUserName, experience,education,age,address));
                        }
                }
            mAdapter.setNewItems(CoachList);
            recyclerViewShow(true);
        }
```

Full code - https://github.com/EladVaknin/Journey